# How do I update a variable in a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm making a menu system for a script I have where I can change the values I need to by using the menu or by passing them as arguments to the script. One of the annoyances I have at the moment is after entering a new value when the menu refreshes, the variable in the menu text does not update to the new values.

```
      $global:drive="C:"

      $title = "Setup 

      "
           $message = "The default variables are:
            VARIABLES TO CHANGE

            1. The Drive Location: $global:drive <<<--- This is the variable that does not update after I change it when I run the script.
       "

      $one = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&1 Drive", "The Drive Location:"

      $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($one)

     :OuterLoop do 
{ 
    for ($i = 1; )
    {

      $result =  $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1) 

    switch ($result)
        {
            0 {$global:drive = Read-Host "Drive is $global:drive .Set the  Drive Location";
                "The Drive is now: $global:drive";
                break;}

          }

                }
}

 while ($y -ne 100)
```

Initially I did not set the variable to to global but read on here that that might help. It did not but it did not hurt either. I also tried setting it to script too. The variable does change, so this is cosmetic more than anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, but mine changes in the menu.  The only thing I did was comment out your first `$global:drive="C:"`.  If this is always at the top of the script, then `$global:drive` will always display `C:`.

You can use the following code to check for the existance of a variable, then assign the value if it doesn't already exist:

```
if $(!(Get-Variable -Name Drive -Scope global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { $global:drive="C:" }
```

If the global variable `Drive` exists, it will do nothing.  If it doesn't exist, `$global:drive` will be set to `C:`.  Hope this helps.

Edit after @Norm comment:

The reason your message isn't updating, is because the `$title` is set outside of the loop.  Because `$Title` is already defined, it doesn't need to change every time the loop runs. Simply move the declaration for `$Title` inside the loop before the line `$result =  $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)`. This should fix the problem you are having.

Edit2: I'm sorry, it's `$message` that needs moved, not `$title`

Comment: Thanks Nick. The code I gave was inaccurate as is part if a larger set and I had to hack it down a little to get to the point. Doing so I left off the while loop. If you run that again, you should see what I mean. You brought up a great point though. Thanks

Comment: OH MAN THAT WAS SOOOO OBVIOUS. Thanks Nick. I just keep telling myself... DUH1 :)

Comment: No problem, we've all done the same thing at some point or another :)